# NetBeans 11 built .jar file gives ClassNotFoundException if ant project used libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

So I have a java Ant Project in NetBeans with libraries. Whenever I compile the project and execute the resulting jar file in the dist folder, I get a ClassNotFoundException. I think if I use libraries, there should be a lib folder in the dist directory. But there isn't any in my case. Note that this Exception isn't thrown when I only debug the project. Then it works perfectly fine.

I did this on both Linux and Windows with JDK 11, default settings in everything, and I always have the same problem.

Comment: Did you enable the "Copy Dependent Libraries" option in the "Packaing" section of the project properties?

Comment: Yes I have. I once made it work in windows. That was the first time I tried building a library project. After that, it never worked again.

Comment: If that is a "library project" that changes everything. I think this only works if the project also has a main class. The project _using_ your library project will then be responsible for copying all needed jars.

Comment: OK, I've got to admit, that my words weren't chosen very wisely. I just meant to say, that my project uses libraries.